# Async for loop not working in Android javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm doing some ajax like this, which works on my iOS device and desktop, but not on Android. In fact nothing in a for loop cycle works, including promises. I can get this to work easily on iOS and desktop, just not Android. Anyone else face this problem?

```
for(var x = 0; x < fbListOfAlbumsTotal; x++) {
  (function(cntr) {
    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/' + fbListOfAlbumsTotal[cntr] + '/photos/?fields=picture,album', ["user_photos"], function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    },function error(error){console.log(error);});
  })(x);
}
```

Comment: Any errors ????

Comment: No errors, but it only prints out the last iteration.

Comment: you should not create functions in a loop anyway...and where are you using promises at the moment? i only see an immediate function, which is pretty old school. you can try putting the api calls together in a loop, and then use Promise.all to use all api calls.

Comment: As I stated in the post, I did try using promises, which works fine on desktop and iOS. I can post the code if necessary, but the problem remains the same, which is the point I'm trying to make. I'm not even sure what to call this bug besides "Android not allowing me traverse async process in both promises and IIFEs"